# C# create an array from specific values of dictionnary

Tags: c#, arrays, dictionary

I've been looking for answers but for some reasons all I found doesn't match with my use.
I'm not very familiar to c#, I have a dictionary

```
public Dictionary<int, int> deck = new Dictionary<int, int>();
```

I want to take ten first values of this dictionary and put it in an array like

```
public string[] cardP1 = new string[10];
```

, I tried some things with .Take or .CopyTo, I also played with the Values but it is still not working.

Comment: what do you want in your array? the key, the value or both?

Comment: I want both key and value, key is the card number, value is its suit

Comment: your dictionary key and values are integers do you really want them in string?

Comment: Not necessary, just need to extract ten first values of dictionary, but I guess it would be better for my next use if i kept it as a string[]

Comment: `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` does not preserve order, and order of elements in it is not defined, so talking about *N first elements* in a dictionary is not quite correct.

Comment: Your question is incomplete and/or incorrect. What do first values mean? .NET Dictionary doesn't preserve order. Do you want to sort keys? You have Dictionary<int,int> but want to put in to string array. What for?

Comment: Well I didn't know that..

Comment: Actually the string is just to be shown in a console.writeline test. I did'nt know that dictionary don't have orders, I wanted to take for example values [0] to values[10] and send those values in my array cardP1[]

Comment: have a look at my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45897752/4273199) while it may not be the best, it will give you the wanted result. (i currently don't have enough time to write more)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use LINQ very easily like this :

```
var q = (from p in deck.Keys select p).Take(10).ToArray();
```

if you want Values you can just change the `deck.keys` to `deck.values`

it will give you the 10 first keys.

**EDIT** Or as Jakub Dąbek commented :

```
var items  = deck.Keys.Take(10).ToArray();
```

Comment: Or just do `deck.Keys.Take(10).ToArray();`

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
if(deck.Count>=10)
{
    cardP1 = deck.Take(10).Select(x => x.Value.ToString()).ToArray();
}
```

Or if you want to have some custom string for example: Card 1: 4

you can go with:

```
cardP1 = deck.Take(10).Select(x => string.Format("Card {0}: {1}", x.Key, x.Value) ).ToArray();
```